# Set items colors in ListView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I have a JavaFX `ListView` which contains objects (represented by the name). I want to color each item's name according to its severity (one of the objects' fields). Is it possible? If it is, how can I do it?

For example, I have a list of news around the world in a list view and each new has a field whether is an important new or not, if it is, I want to color the new's name in the list view by red, otherwise I want to color it by green.

My code:

```
private ListView<String> newsList;

private Vector<IntelligenceNew> newsListVec;

private ObservableList<String> newsListObserver;

public void initializeListView(IntelligenceSource source) {
    newsListObserver = FXCollections.observableArrayList ();
    newsListVec = new Vector<>();
    for (IntelligenceNew news : source.getListOfNews()){
        newsListObserver.add(news.getName());
        newsListVec.add(news);
    }

    newsList.setItems(newsListObserver);
}
```

While inserting the news to the ListView, I want to check the severity of each new and then color it by red or green.

Comment: No need to close this question, the OP provided an MCVE so it became clear what he was asking. I looked around for a similar question on my favorite search engine, and couldn't find one in top links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Create a class extending [`ListCell<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListCell.html) (say, named `YourFormatCell`)
- In the override for [`ListCell<String>.updateItem(String item, boolean empty)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem-T-boolean-) set the cell's color using [`setTextFill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setTextFill-javafx.scene.paint.Paint-) (take `isSelected()` into account if needed)
- Register `YourFormatCell` using [`ListView<String>.setCellFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-)
- More information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html)

---

```
public class YourFormatCell extends ListCell<String> {
    @Override 
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(item);
        setTextFill(isSevere(item)?Color.RED:Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

---

```
newsList.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
    @Override 
    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
        return new YourFormatCell();
    }
});
```

Comment: It's working great. Thanks to you I saved few minutes of my life :)
It's also good to add a null check
`if (item != null) setTextFill(isSevere(item)?Color.RED:Color.GREEN);`
because sometimes item is null (or handle that in isSevere method)